# Trancoding a video with vlc and the MPEG-4 codec with a video bit rate

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-codecs, bitrate, mpeg4

When I try to trancode a video with vlc using the MPEG-4 codec and a video bit rate, I get the following error :

```
Either both buffer size and max rate or neither must be specified
```

Here is the command line I used :

> vlc -vvv myvideo.m2ts --sout-ffmpeg-strict=-2 --sout
>   '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=2000,acodec=mp4a,ab=96}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=/path/file.mp4}'

It seems that I can't specify a video bit rate with the MPEG-4 codec. (If I remove the vb option, it works).
So how can I specify a video bit rate with the MPEG-4 codec ?